# How to pass an empty parameter into action with cleos

Tags: action, account-name

I have an action that looks like the following:

```
hello ( name person ) {

    if ( name == 0 ) {
        ; // do something
    } else {
        ; // do something else
    }
}
```

and I wanted to pass nothing in to the 'parameter'.  I try

```
cleos push action myaccount hello '[""]'
```

but I get this error:

```
Failed with error: Parse Error (4) Couldn't parse uint64_t
```

and when I try

```
cleos push action myaccount hello '["0"]'
```

I get

```
Error 3010001: Invalid name
Name should be less than 13 characters and only contains the following 
symbol .12345abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
Error Details:
Name not properly normalized (name: 0, normalized: )
```

How do I choose to pass in an empty name parameter?

---

**EDIT:** changed action name for 'hi' to 'hello'

Comment: Did my solution work?

Answer (score 1):

The correct format is:

`cleos push action myaccount hello '{"person":"0"}'`

Note: The name of the action is `hello`, not `hi`

Answer (score -2):

push empty data with transaction:

```
cleos push action myaccount hello '{}'
```